# How to interpret these Jain statements in terms of omega consistency? [hint only]

Tags: logic, paradox

[ω-consistent theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory):

> In mathematical logic, an ω-consistent (or omega-consistent, also
>   called numerically segregative[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory)) theory is a theory (collection of
>   sentences) that is not only (syntactically) consistent (that is, does
>   not prove a contradiction), but also avoids proving certain infinite
>   combinations of sentences that are intuitively contradictory. The name
>   is due to Kurt Gödel, who introduced the concept in the course of
>   proving the incompleteness theorem.

Now in Jain [dialectic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectic) we have the following statements:

> These seven propositions also known as saptabhangi are:
>
> ```
> syād-asti: "in some ways it is"
> syād-nāsti: "in some ways it is not"
> syād-asti-nāsti: "in some ways it is and it is not"
> syād-asti-avaktavyaḥ: "in some ways it is and it is indescribable"
> syād-nāsti-avaktavyaḥ: "in some ways it is not and it is indescribable"
> syād-asti-nāsti-avaktavyaḥ: "in some ways it is, it is not and it is indescribable"
> syād-avaktavyaḥ: "in some ways it is indescribable"
> ```

I just need a hint to convert the latter sentences to logical form.

Comment: Would it be a hint to suggest you think about which of these seven propositions you would consider to contradict each other?

Comment: I think computability, or computational complexity, is likely to be a better framework for extracting any sort of classical formal expression of these sentences (mapping the properties of "is" and "is not" to answers for instances of a yes/no problem, i.e. to possession of qualities rather than mere existence). Of course, the presentation suggests that you might prefer to simply consider a paraconsistent logic instead, which embraces contradictions rather than rejecting them; but then omega-consistency perhaps becomes a less interesting concept in that context anyway.

Comment: I can't see what contribution that omega-consistency can make to Jain thought. Its a technical requirement that Godels requires for his theorem to go though, rather than being something of independent interest on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recast in a classical logical framework, you could start with a family `M` of models for which your truth-statements are interpretable (i.e. they refer to things in those models); if these models are all reasonable approximations of reality (even if they differ in some details), then "in some ways it is" means "there exists `m` in `M` s.t. `p` is true in `m`".  Let `D` be a decidability function (i.e. `D(p,m)` implies that there is a proof of `p` given model `m`--whether you want to work with different models or different sets of truth statements is a more complex issue than I have time to think through).  Then "in some ways it is indescribable" means that "there exists `m` in `M` s.t. `!D(p,m)`" (where `!` means "not")--it might be true or it might not, but you can't show it.

So then we have these three fundamental statements:

```
A: exists `m` in `M` s.t. `p`
B: exists `n` in `M` s.t. `!p`
C: exists `r` in `M` s.t. `!D(p,r)`
```

And the seven propositions are just an exhaustive combinations of these:

```
A
B
A & B
A & C
B & C
A & B & C
C
```

(omitting the trivial case of no statement at all).

I am not sure this exactly maps onto the Jain propositions, but at least it's a start in that direction.